# HTML: Should i <link/> files local or online?

Tags: html

**This:**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**or this:**

```
<link href="library/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What is the best to do and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs some quantification.

It is best for YOUR server to load resources from a CDN.

It is perhaps better for the end user to load from your server if your server is faster/has better availability than the CDN, otherwise it is ALSO better for the user, who may even have the css already from other requests.